# Bifurcation diagram and bifurcation value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

Determine the bifurcation values of $\dot{x} = x(x-r^2)$, and sketch the bifurcation diagram.

**My attempt:** First, we see that if $f(x_0, r_0) = Df(x_0, r_0) = 0$, then $x_0$ is a non-hyperbolic critical point and $r_0$ is a bifurcation value. We see that this only occurs when $(x_0, r_0) = (0,0)$, so this is the only bifurcation value. Now, for each $r_0\neq 0$, the solution would increase without bound for $x_0 > \sqrt{r_0}$ and $x_0 < 0$, and decrease for $0 < x_0< \sqrt{r_0}$. I don't know how to demonstrate these information on the bifurcation diagram though:( Can someone please help?

Comment: @Variable: Yes!

Comment: @Variable: of course I got them. The phase portrait would be a family of parabola in the cases you mentioned, but what about other cases? And how would the change from stable to unstable be demonstrated on the diagram?

Comment: @Variable: how do you show the change for stability then? Can you kindly post your diagram?

Comment: @GaussTheBauss: can you give this problem a try? Please post a bifurcation diagram, as it would help me a lot to solve my current concerns about change of stability at equilibrium points.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not familiar with bifurcation.

Comment: Could you please review the equation, it is incompatible with your solutions. Should it be $\dot x = x(x^2-r)$ or even $\dot x = x(r-x^2)$?

Comment: Why there is an incompatibility here? Do you mind explaining? I checked the problem statement, and it's indeed what I wrote above.

Comment: @Variable: here's my thought with the assumption that the problem above is "correct": All I see is that when r=0r=0, x˙=x2x˙=x2, which is structurally unstable, so $r=0$ is a bifurcation point. Based on my current bifurcation diagram, the $r$-axis is dash line (aka, stable) across positive and negative $r$, while the parabola $x=r^2$ is a dotted curve (aka, unstable). Not sure if this is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the original problem, we have two critical points $x = 0 , r^2$. The following phase portraits show four different values of $r$, but note that they are identical for $\pm r$.

$r = -10$

[image]

$r = -3$

[image]

$r = -1$

[image]

$r = 0$

[image]

Comment: interesting...I can't see any implications these phase portraits have towards the bifurcation value $r=0$, as well as the nature of the bifurcation diagram, which should be composed of only the $x-axis$ + the parabola $x=r^2$. Do you see any implications w.r.t bifurcation diagram based on these phase portraits? Those are 2 different things.

Comment: When you have a bifurcation, you will most definitely see a qualitative difference in the phase portraits! That is why I did not post these results earlier and why I believe LutzL was correct in his comment that something was written incorrectly. It is just not interesting as written. The most interesting thing I see is at $r = -3$. You should do an experiment with a system that you know the bifurcation diagram of and draw phase portraits to convince yourself of what I am saying.

Comment: it's weird that even though $r=0$ is a bifurcation value, no qualitative difference shown in the phase portrait you posted. Hmm...

Comment: It is hard to see the details in those picture, but you can redraw it and make the PP larger in the area of change and then you can see more details of the change, but structurally, it looks very equivalent (like the small offset that it is).

Comment: I finally saw that small change!! Thank you for your patience. Can you kindly help me with part (c) in this problem, or at least, confirm if my argument for it in the comment is right? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590311/polar-coordinate-system-of-odes

Comment: @Moo : these images were made with Matemathica ? Can you show commands ?

Comment: Effectively, it would be something like: StreamPlot[{1,x(x−r^2)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, - 5, 5}]. You would vary "r" for each plot and can even make a GIF movie.

Answer (score 2):

A bifurcation is usually a point where a branch of stable stationary points switches to unstable in its smooth continuation. Usually there will emerge two new stable branches of stationary points.

The only rewriting of the initial equation satisfying these criteria is
$$
\dot x = x(r-x^2).
$$
For $r<0$, $x_0=0$ is a stable stationary point, for $r>0$ it becomes unstable and $x_0=\pm\sqrt{r}$ are the new stationary points.

The linearization at $x_0=\sqrt{r}$ is
$$
\dot u=\frac d{dt}(\sqrt r+u)=(\sqrt r+u)(-u)(2\sqrt r+u)=-2ru-3\sqrt r u^2-u^3\\=-2r·u+O(u^2)
$$
so that these points remain stable for all $r>0$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Assume your corrected problem is correct... Where does u come from? And your bifurcation point is $r=0$ right? Can you please sketch the bifurcation diagram? I also don't see how "$\frac{d}{dt}(\sqrt{r}+u) = ...$"

Comment: $u$ is the (infinitesimal) offset at the fixed point, i.e., it is a method to express that $x(t)=\sqrt r+u(t)$ is close to $x_0=\sqrt r$.

Comment: I finally got where you get the equation. But I still wonder why the original equation does not make sense? It still has 2 critical points at $\pm \sqrt{r}$, but they would be UNSTABLE for all $r>0$ in that case. Anyway, how can we draw the bifurcation diagram with these information?

Comment: by the way, is $r=0$ the only bifurcation value for this problem?

Comment: Yes, as you need a stationary point with multiplicity greater than one. For all other $r$, the 3 simple roots are distinct.

Comment: No, the original equation has one stable point at $x_0=0$ and one unstable point at $x_0=r^2$ for all $r$. In a very broad sense one could still call $r=0$ a bifurcation point, but it is rather difficult to see the image of a fork therein.

Comment: I'm not sure why it has anything to do with multiplicity of stationary point. All I see is that when $r=0$, $\dot{x} = x^2$, which is structurally unstable, so $r=0$ is a bifurcation point. Btw, how do you know it's a pitchfork bifurcation for the original equation? You're correct about the unstable point $x_0 = r^2$. Based on my current bifurcation diagram, the $r$-axis is dash line across positive and negative $r$, while the parabola $x = r^2$ is dotted curve. Not sure if this is correct?