# Equilibrium of a system of 2nd-order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given 
$$
\ddot{x} = \begin{cases}
-x + c\cdot \operatorname{sgn}(x)& |x| > c\\
 0 & |x|\leq c
\end{cases}
$$ 
where $c > 0$ are some given constants.

(a) Find all equilibria

(b) Graph the phase portrait of that system

(c) Make the conjecture, and prove it, about the nature of the non-equilibrium solutions.

**My attempt:** For part (a), From the given system, we see that the only case where the RHS is $0$ is when $|x|< c$ (the equation, $- x + c\cdot \operatorname{sgn}(x) = 0$, only has roots $x=\pm c$, which contradicts to the condition $|x| > c$). Thus all equilibria $:= \left\{x\in R\ |\  |x| < c\right\}$.

For part (b), it seems weird to me that the only possible solution is $x(t) = At+B$, where $A$ and $B$ are some constants such that $|x| < c$ for all $t\in R$. This means $A=0$ is the only choice, so $x(t) = B$ ($B < c$), is the only solution. So the phase portrait is just the horizontal line $x=B$. For the other equation, I couldn't see how a specific solution $x(t)$ that satisfies the constraint $|x| > c$ AND the equation: $\ddot{x} + x = c\cdot \operatorname{sgn}(x)$ exists.

For part (c), all the non-equilibrium solutions don't exist, based on what I found in part (b).

**My question:** I'm skeptical with my answers above. So I hope someone can try this problem out and/or give me some thoughts about my work.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this difficult problem?

Comment: @Variable: I thought through it again, and was not satisfied (posted my questions in the comment below). It seems to me the answer was wrong:P

Comment: @Variable: why didn't you post your work, and your answers, so that I can learn from it, and we can discuss if it has any problems? My major trouble is, I still don't think the 1st 2nd-order ODEs has any solutions due to the constraint $|x(t)| > c$ for every t.

Comment: @Variable: many thanks!! Did you actually get a solution for the 1st 2nd-order ODE with the constraint satisfied for every $t$?

Comment: @Variable: well, it can be done by hand though:P The question was from a qual exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is inspired by the approach used in the amazing book "Theory of Oscillators" by A.A. Andronov, A.A. Vitt and S.E. Khaikin (See Section $III-I$ and $VII-9$).

We are given 
$$ \tag 1
\ddot{x} = \begin{cases}
-x + c\cdot \operatorname{sgn}(x)& |x| > c\\
 0 & |x|\leq c
\end{cases}
$$ 
where $c > 0$ is a constant.

We can re-write $(1)$ as a system of first order equations:

$$ \tag 2 \begin{align} x' &= y \\ y' &= -x + c ~\mbox{sgn}(x) \end{align}$$

From $(2)$, we have that all points in the interval $| x | \le c, y = 0$ are equilibrium points.

Now, to see what is going on with the phase portrait, lets consider three cases.

**Case 1:** $~x \lt -c$, from $(2)$, we get the DEQ

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{-x-c}{y} \implies y^2 + (x + c)^2 = C_1$$

This gives us semicircles centered at $(-c, 0)$.

**Case 2:** $~-c \le x \le c$, from $(2)$, we get the DEQ

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0 \implies y = C_2$$

This gives us straight lines.

**Case 3:** $~x \gt c$, from $(2)$, we get the DEQ

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{-x+c}{y} \implies y^2 + (x - c)^2 = C_3$$

This gives us semicircles centered at $(c, 0)$.

From these three cases, we see that we have a phase portrait with semicircles, where the variable $c$ is elongating those. We can now draw the phase portrait with direction fields by hand as:

[image]

Of course, I wanted to try and verify this using numerical methods and needed help with Mathematica to get it to work. Here are three cases for $c = 1, 5, 10$ (sorry I didn't add the direction arrows, but already spent too much time with it). If you were to overlay them, you would have the hand drawn graphic shown above.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Do you see how the phase portrait is being elongated by the choice of the variable $c$, since those are constant phase lines? The other areas give us the two sets of semicircles as described by the three cases.

With a bunch of time, it should be possible to draw a general phase portrait or vector field showing many initial conditions and it will look like the items already shown, but with many elongated semicircles and direction fields.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful solution! It's way easier after we de-couple the system:((( I think yours is clearer with very nice picture. So the conjecture on part (c) is just this I think: every non-equilibrium solutions would belong to parts of the semicircle THAT is not on the x-axis in the xy-plane. Is this correct? Also, what do you mean with "general" phae portrait? I thought the one you drew above is the general one already?

Comment: Yes, if you look at what I wrote for the equilibrium points, everything else has to belong to the semicircles.

Comment: nice work(+1). i saw this example or one very similar to in lefchetz's non linear vibrations published by princeton.

Comment: @abel: Thank you. I think I might have that book and will go back and look at that. I also have another similar one and do recall seeing problems of this type in them also.

Comment: @Variable: wait a minute... I think my due diligence found some problems again. For Case 2, if we solve for $x$, we would get $x = C_2t+D$ for C_2, D are some constants. We can only make sure $|x|\leq c$ if $C_2=0$, and $D\leq c$. So $x = D$ where $-c\leq D\leq c$ is the only solution in this case. So the graph should have upper and lower bounds on the range of the horizontal line.

Comment: For case $2$, we have $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0 \implies y(x) = c_2$. These are just the straight lines. Their length is given by the choice of $c$. You can see this in each of the phase portraits.

Comment: @Variable: do you mind helping me with another problem? I'm still looking for the confirmation on my answers in the comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590167/bifurcation-diagram-and-bifurcation-value

Comment: @Variable: for part (c), all the non-equilibrium points must be on the semicircles or the horizontal lines except the x-axis.

Comment: I think that observation is correct, however, doesn't the original problem restrict $c \gt 0$? If we allowed $c = 0$, we would get a perfect circle. Since this case is not allowed, your statement is correct that all non-equilibrium points must be on semicircles or horizontal lines.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>c$ set $y=x-c$ to obtain the ODE $\ddot y+y=0$ which gives upper half circles in the $(x,\dot x)$ phase space.

Similarly lower half circles for $x<c$.

For the solution continuation in $(x,\dot x)=(c,-r)$, $r\ne 0$ you get the line $x(t)=c-rt$, $\dot x(t)=-r$ which at time $t=2c/r$ reaches the point $(x,\dot x)=(-c,r)$ and continues in a half circle towards $(-c,r)$, then in a line straight up to $(c,r)$ and an upper half circle closing the stadium oval.

This leaves the consideration of the points $(x,\dot x)\in[-c,c]×\{0\}$

Comment: Thank you for your help. So your set of equilibrium is the same as mine? Btw, did you see my last comments on the "bifurcation diagram" problem? Hope to hear your further thought.

Comment: Btw, how did you get the weird phase space $(x,\dot{x})$? Can you try and state the clear answers for part (c)? I know your description above pretty much "solves" part (b), so I will try to follow it.

Comment: I don't see how you can get $(x,\dot{x}) = (c,-r)$. Since $x=c$ is a constant, $\dot{x} = 0$, not $-r$.

Comment: 1) Yes, there is only so many ways to get zero. 2) for a second order ODE the phase space is the points $(x,\dot x)$. 3) This is an initial point for the next segment of the solution, not the parametrization of that segment.